# Can you match a nested state with string paths in xstate?

Tags: state, xstate

From the [@xstate/react](https://github.com/davidkpiano/xstate/tree/master/packages/xstate-react) GitHub repo:

> ... for hierarchical and parallel machines, the state values will be objects, not strings. In this case, it's better to use state.matches(...)

Which looks like this:

```js
if (current.matches({ loading: 'user' })) {
  return /* ... */;
}
```

But could you replace `{ loading: 'user' }` with `"loading.user"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely! At least for the current version of xstate (4.6.7) and @xstate/react (0.8.1), the following if statements are equivalent:

```js
if (current.matches({ loading: 'user' })) {
  return /* ... */;
}
```

```js
if (current.matches("loading.user")) {
  return /* ... */;
}
```